# LINQ to Entity Framework does not generate working query for HANA

Tags: vb.net, linq, entity-framework-6, hana

I have a project that I am trying to get working on HANA, the original used Entity Framework and SQL Server.

I've hit several problems, but it does look as though code-first contexts have a chance of working, but a pretty simple setting fetch as follows:

```
    Dim qry = (From s In _context.Settings
               Where s.Name.ToLower = Name.ToLower
               Select s.Value).DefaultIfEmpty(DefaultValue)
    Return qry.SingleOrDefault()
```

Results in the following SQL code:

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN ("Project1"."C1" IS NULL) THEN N'3' ELSE "Project1"."Value" END AS "C1"
FROM   
    (SELECT 1 AS X) AS "SingleRowTable1"
LEFT OUTER JOIN  
    (SELECT 
         "Extent1"."Value" AS "Value", 
         CAST(1 AS tinyint) AS "C1"
     FROM  
         "BJT_TEST2"."IndicatorSettings" AS "Extent1"
     WHERE 
         ((LOWER("Extent1"."Name")) = (LOWER(     :p__linq__0     ))) OR
((LOWER("Extent1"."Name") IS NULL) AND (LOWER(     :p__linq__0__01 ) IS NULL)) ) AS "Project1"
ON cast(1 as boolean) = cast(1 as boolean)
```

This looks great, and does actually work if I add "FROM DUMMY" after "SELECT 1 AS X". I'm using the provider from "Sap.Data.Hana" from HDB client version 1.20. Is there any way to configure the HANA provider so that code generated from LINQ is syntactically correct for HANA (that being the point of the HANA provider)?

Also, am I completely barking up the wrong tree here? I have no problem using PetaPoco instead and writing my own queries, but I am short on time, and I had hoped to use what's there.

Comment: I've been tinkering, and it looks like the faulty code comes from SingleOrDefault, but not from FirstOrDefault, so I may be able to get by with that.

Comment: I decided to recode and use PetaPoco - Hana EF Provider defaults to using AutoMigration = On, which seems dangerous - I haven't had a change to test with a configuration class, but anybody attempting to use the HANA EF provider absolutely needs to be certain that it won't change the DB schema when you don't want to.